# Miniconda + PyGObject: Gtk.Spinner not visible/ how to use system application appearance

Tags: python, spinner, gtk3, pygobject, miniconda

I am writing an GUI application using PyGObject with GTK+ 3.16.6 in a miniconda virtual environment (Python 3.6.3). Within my application I want to use a Gtk.Spinner, but this widget is not shown when I start my program within the miniconda environment. If I start the application outside of the virtual environment (using Python and the libraries that are installed on my system), the widget is shown as expected. In addition the 'venv-version' does not use the application appearance that is configured in the system which makes sense to me, but the missing Gtk.Spinner does really bother me.

Here is how the application looks like (the spinner is in the bottom right corner):

Started in the virtual environment
[image]

Started 'natively'
[image]

I guess that I need to set some environment variable, but I have no clue what to add and how to do that permanent in the virtual environment. I would like to get that spinner visible, the rest of the appearance is not that important. Can you help me?

Thank you in advance!

For completeness, here is the output of `conda list -e` for the virtual environment:

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
at-spi2-atk=2.16.0=1
at-spi2-core=2.16.0=1
atk=2.16.0=2
bleach=2.0.0=py36h688b259_0
ca-certificates=2017.11.5=0
cairo=1.14.8=0
certifi=2017.11.5=py36_0
dbus=1.8.20=1
dbus-glib=0.104=1
decorator=4.1.2=py36hd076ac8_0
entrypoints=0.2.3=py36h1aec115_2
expat=2.1.0=0
fontconfig=2.12.1=3
freetype=2.5.5=2
gdk-pixbuf=2.30.8=3
gettext=0.19.7=1
glib=2.51.4=0
gmp=6.1.2=h6c8ec71_1
gobject-introspection=1.51.3=py36_0
gst-plugins-base=1.8.0=0
gstreamer=1.8.0=0
gtk=3.16.6=2
harfbuzz=1.0.1=3
html5lib=0.999999999=py36h2cfc398_0
icu=54.1=0
intel-openmp=2018.0.0=h15fc484_7
ipykernel=4.6.1=py36hbf841aa_0
ipython=6.1.0=py36hc72a948_1
ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py36hb52b0d5_0
ipywidgets=7.0.0=py36h7b55c3a_0
jedi=0.10.2=py36h552def0_0
jinja2=2.9.6=py36h489bce4_1
jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
jsonschema=2.6.0=py36h006f8b5_0
jupyter=1.0.0=py36h9896ce5_0
jupyter_client=5.1.0=py36h614e9ea_0
jupyter_console=5.2.0=py36he59e554_1
jupyter_core=4.3.0=py36h357a921_0
libcroco=0.6.8=1
libedit=3.1=heed3624_0
libepoxy=1.3.1=1
libffi=3.2.1=3
libgcc=7.2.0=h69d50b8_2
libgcc-ng=7.2.0=h7cc24e2_2
libgsf=1.14.34=1
libiconv=1.14=4
libpng=1.6.28=2
librsvg=2.40.10=3
libsodium=1.0.15=hf101ebd_0
libstdcxx-ng=7.2.0=h7a57d05_2
libtiff=4.0.8=h90200ff_9
libxcb=1.12=h84ff03f_3
libxml2=2.9.4=0
markupsafe=1.0=py36hd9260cd_1
mistune=0.8.1=py36h3d5977c_0
mkl=2018.0.0=hb491cac_4
nbconvert=5.3.1=py36hb41ffb7_0
nbformat=4.4.0=py36h31c9010_0
ncurses=6.0=h9df7e31_2
notebook=5.2.1=py36h690a4eb_0
numpy=1.13.3=py36ha12f23b_0
openssl=1.0.2l=0
pandoc=1.19.2.1=hea2e7c5_1
pandocfilters=1.4.2=py36ha6701b7_1
pango=1.40.0=0
pcre=8.39=0
pexpect=4.2.1=py36h3b9d41b_0
pickleshare=0.7.4=py36h63277f8_0
pip=9.0.1=py36_0
pixman=0.34.0=0
prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py36h17d85b1_0
ptyprocess=0.5.2=py36h69acd42_0
pycairo=1.13.3=py36_0
pygments=2.2.0=py36h0d3125c_0
pygobject=3.25.1=py36_0
pyqt=5.6.0=py36_2
python=3.6.3=h0ef2715_3
python-dateutil=2.6.1=py36h88d3b88_1
pyzmq=16.0.2=py36h3b0cf96_2
qt=5.6.2=5
qtconsole=4.3.1=py36h8f73b5b_0
readline=7.0=ha6073c6_4
setuptools=36.7.2=py36_0
simplegeneric=0.8.1=py36h2cb9092_0
sip=4.18.1=py36h51ed4ed_2
six=1.11.0=py36h372c433_1
sqlite=3.20.1=hb898158_2
system=5.8=2
terminado=0.6=py36ha25a19f_0
testpath=0.3.1=py36h8cadb63_0
tk=8.6.7=hc745277_3
tornado=4.5.2=py36h1283b2a_0
traitlets=4.3.2=py36h674d592_0
wcwidth=0.1.7=py36hdf4376a_0
webencodings=0.5.1=py36h800622e_1
wheel=0.30.0=py_1
widgetsnbextension=3.0.2=py36hd01bb71_1
xz=5.2.3=0
zeromq=4.2.2=hbedb6e5_2
zlib=1.2.11=0
```